# Having errors with table creation in Entity Framework Code First with MySql Connector.

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm having errors when creating the table Order in MySql.

I get a "you have an error in mysql near 'Order (OrderId) ON UPDATE NO ACTION..."

It only happens on this table, with any type of foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the Generated Script (mysql connector 6.6.5) i noticed that in the creation of the foreign keys the table Order was not written like `Order` and thus was the reserved word **order by**.
My solution was to rename the table with the Table attribute in the Order class.
I'm reporting the bug where appropiate

Good luck